# Using dplyr quosure custom function with mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

I am trying to build a helper function that extract the digits in the column given in argument. I'm able to use my function inside `mutate` (and repeat it for all columns of interest), but it doesn't seems to work inside `mutate_at`.

Here is an example of what my data looks like :

```
> set.seed(20190928)
> evalYr <- 2018
> n <- 5
> (df <- data.frame(
+     AY = sample(2016:2019, n, replace = T),
+     Pay00 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
+     Pay01 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
+     Pay02 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
+     Pay03 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000)
+ ))
    AY     Pay00     Pay01     Pay02     Pay03
1 2018 2520.3772 2338.9490  919.8245  629.1657
2 2016  259.7804 1543.4450  661.6488 2382.7916
3 2018 2446.3075  312.5143 2297.9717  942.5627
4 2017 1386.6288 4179.0352 2370.2669 1846.5838
5 2018  541.8261 2104.4589 2622.1758 2606.0694
```

So I've build (using `dplyr` syntax) this helper to mutate on every `PayXX` column I have :

```
# Helper function to get the number inside column `PayXX` name
f1 <- function(pmt) enquo(pmt) %>% quo_name() %>% str_extract('(\\d)+') %>% as.numeric()
```

This function is working fine with `dplyr::mutate` :

```
> df %>% mutate(Pay00_numcol = f1(Pay00),
+               Pay01_numcol = f1(Pay01),
+               Pay02_numcol = f1(Pay02),
+               Pay03_numcol = f1(Pay03))
    AY     Pay00     Pay01     Pay02     Pay03 Pay00_numcol Pay01_numcol Pay02_numcol Pay03_numcol
1 2018 2520.3772 2338.9490  919.8245  629.1657            0            1            2            3
2 2016  259.7804 1543.4450  661.6488 2382.7916            0            1            2            3
3 2018 2446.3075  312.5143 2297.9717  942.5627            0            1            2            3
4 2017 1386.6288 4179.0352 2370.2669 1846.5838            0            1            2            3
5 2018  541.8261 2104.4589 2622.1758 2606.0694            0            1            2            3
```

But when I try to use the same function inside `mutate_at`, it returns NA's :

```
> df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Pay')), list(numcol = ~f1(.)))
    AY     Pay00     Pay01     Pay02     Pay03 Pay00_numcol Pay01_numcol Pay02_numcol Pay03_numcol
1 2018 2520.3772 2338.9490  919.8245  629.1657           NA           NA           NA           NA
2 2016  259.7804 1543.4450  661.6488 2382.7916           NA           NA           NA           NA
3 2018 2446.3075  312.5143 2297.9717  942.5627           NA           NA           NA           NA
4 2017 1386.6288 4179.0352 2370.2669 1846.5838           NA           NA           NA           NA
5 2018  541.8261 2104.4589 2622.1758 2606.0694           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

Anyone ever had a similar problem? How do I deal with the `mutate_at` function in this case?

Thanks,

## Reproductible example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
set.seed(20190928)
evalYr <- 2018
n <- 5
(df <- data.frame(
    AY = sample(2016:2019, n, replace = T),
    Pay00 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
    Pay01 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
    Pay02 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000),
    Pay03 = rgamma(n, 2, 1/1000)
))

# Helper function to get the number inside column `PayXX` name
f1 <- function(pmt) enquo(pmt) %>% quo_name() %>% str_extract('(\\d)+') %>% as.numeric()

# Working
df %>% mutate(Pay00_numcol = f1(Pay00),
              Pay01_numcol = f1(Pay01),
              Pay02_numcol = f1(Pay02),
              Pay03_numcol = f1(Pay03))

# Not working
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Pay')), list(numcol = ~f1(.)))
```

Comment: I don't know whey, but following code works: `df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Pay')), list(numcol = f1))`. Somehow  this syntax `~f1(.)` doesn't work.

Comment: FYI `stringr` is one of the packages loaded by `tidyverse`, so you don't need to load it separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way I thought of is that this might be easier with reshaping the data. However, it still takes a tangle of `tidyr` functions to get 1) a column of "Pay00", "Pay01", etc; 2) extract the numbers; 3) manipulate so you can use `tidyr::spread` to get back to wide-shaped; and 4) spread and remove the "_value" bit I tacked on.

I believe there's a nicer way to do this with the recent version of `tidyr`, since the new `pivot_wider` function should be able to take more than one column as `value`. I haven't messed with this at all, but maybe someone else can write that up.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(key, value, -AY, -rowid) %>%
  mutate(numcol = as.numeric(str_extract(key, "\\d+$"))) %>%
  gather(key = coltype, value, value, numcol) %>%
  unite(key, key, coltype) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(AY, ends_with("value"), ends_with("numcol")) %>%
  rename_all(str_remove, "_value")
#>     AY     Pay00     Pay01     Pay02     Pay03 Pay00_numcol Pay01_numcol
#> 1 2018 2520.3772 2338.9490  919.8245  629.1657            0            1
#> 2 2016  259.7804 1543.4450  661.6488 2382.7916            0            1
#> 3 2018 2446.3075  312.5143 2297.9717  942.5627            0            1
#> 4 2017 1386.6288 4179.0352 2370.2669 1846.5838            0            1
#> 5 2018  541.8261 2104.4589 2622.1758 2606.0694            0            1
#>   Pay02_numcol Pay03_numcol
#> 1            2            3
#> 2            2            3
#> 3            2            3
#> 4            2            3
#> 5            2            3
```

Or, if you want to stick with the tidyeval approach: get the names of the columns-as-quosures you're calling your function on. Just be careful that if you use `list(numcol = ~f1(.))` notation, all of those quosures will just come up as `.`

```r
f1 <- function(pmt) {
  str_extract(rlang::as_name(enquo(pmt)), "\\d+$") %>%
    as.numeric()
}

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Pay")), list(numcol = f1))
# same output as prev
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My problem is a bit more complex (I need to do specific calculation that depends on the name of the column, i.e Pay01, Pay02, etc. So the wrangling through gather/spread is definitely what I was looking for.

However, if I wanted to stick with my original approach, and I wanted to pass multiple arguments to function inside .funs (in my real case, f1 has 4 args), how would I deal with this without using the ~ operator?

Thank you for your help, once again.

Comment: Getting too much more complicated might be beyond my tidyeval skills. But you can pass additional arguments inside the `mutate_at` call but outside the `list` call